# Postfix transport map with failover entries?

Tags: postfix, configuration, relay

Postfix relays a few domains to a fixed IP address, or its failover address.

```
1.2.3.4 and 11.12.13.14 (failover)
```

These two IP addresses are where the relay should occur.

Currently, transport_map

```
exemple1.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587
exemple2.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587
```

Is there a way, in case [1.2.3.4] times out, to use the failover automatically, like

```
exemple1.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587
exemple2.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587
exemple1.com   relay:[11.12.13.14]:587
exemple2.com   relay:[11.12.13.14]:587
```

Would that work?

(There is [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/448563/postix-transport-smtp-failover) which is a tad different. Adding multiple IPs to /etc/hosts (or DNS if that was possible) would use either IP. In my case the failover should only be used if the main one times out)

Comment: The [`transport (5) man page`](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) says: *In the сase of the Postfix SMTP/LMTP client, the nexthop field may contain  a  list  of nexthop destinations separated by comma or whitespace (Postfix 3.5 and later).* No further explanation is given about interpretation of such token. Probably it's worth asking in the Postfix users mailing list.

Comment: Great, thanks. We're on Postfix 3.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) though.

Comment: so did it work ? how did you write like this ?
exemple1.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587,relay:[11.12.13.14]:587
exemple2.com   relay:[1.2.3.4]:587,relay:[11.12.13.14]:587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from Postfix 3.5 release notes

> [Feature 20200111] the Postfix SMTP and LMTP client support a list
> of nexthop destinations separated by comma or whitespace. These
> destinations will be tried in the specified order.

> The list form can be specified in relayhost, transport_maps,
> default_transport, and sender_dependent_default_transport_maps.

Examples:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    relayhost = foo.example, bar.example
    default_transport = smtp:foo.example, bar.example.
```

> NOTE: this is an SMTP and LMTP client feature. It does not work for
> other Postfix delivery agents.

If you don't have Postfix 3.5 you can specify the destination as a domain name without brakets - postfix will do MX lookups for that domain name and use MX to send the email.

Comment: Will this work with the `relay:` prefix in transport (syntax in the question). Like `exemple1.com   relay:myMxDnsEntriesHost:587` ? If yes, that's a great idea, as MX includes priorities!