# Postfix sasl_password file and MX resolution

Tags: postfix, sasl, syntax, relay

Thanks to @AlexD [idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088263/postfix-transport-map-with-failover-entries), we'll implement the following transport table in order to simulate a IP failover using the DNS MX resolution (postfix 3.3)

Relay for 2 domains, exemple[12].com

```
exemple1.com   relay:mx.myhost.com:587
exemple2.com   relay:mx.myhost.com:587
```

In DNS

```
A    ip1.myhost.com      1.2.3.4
A    ip2.myhost.com      11.12.13.14

MX   mx.myhost.com   10  ip1.myhost.com
MX   mx.myhost.com   50  ip2.myhost.com
```

The postfix relay should first use ip1 (priority 10) and ip2 (50) if ip1 fails.

Provided that this is correct, next step is the SMTP authentication. The same set of username/password is available for both the ip1 and ip2 connections.

```
user:pass
```

**Question**: in the `sasl_passwd` map, since both ip1 and ip2 use the same user:pass set, can we / should we use the to-be-mx-resolved host (one entry) or do we have to use two identical user/pass entries one for [ip1] and one for [ip2]? (Does the SASL authentication indirectly accepts a host to be MX resolved and then apply the authentication to the resolved entry?)

**a)** Is this sasl_passwd file ok

```
 mx.myhost.com:587   user:pass
```

**b)** or this one

```
 [ip1.myhost.com]:587   user:pass
 [ip2.myhost.com]:587   user:pass
```

**c)** and by the way is this the same as using directly the IPs?

```
 [1.2.3.4]:587       user:pass
 [11.12.13.14]:587   user:pass
```

(provided the A record does not change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_sasl_password_maps) says following:

> **smtp_sasl_password_maps (default: empty)**
> Optional Postfix SMTP client lookup tables with one username:password entry per sender, remote hostname or next-hop domain.

[SASL_README](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl) has the following:

> **Important**

> If you specify the "[" and "]" in the relayhost destination, then you must use the same form in the smtp_sasl_password_maps file.

> If you specify a non-default TCP Port (such as ":submission" or ":587") in the relayhost destination, then you must use the same form in the smtp_sasl_password_maps file.

Example configuration:

```
/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:
    # destination                   credentials
    [mail.isp.example]              username:password
    # Alternative form:
    # [mail.isp.example]:submission username:password
```

So according to the documentation quoted above, you need to write your destination the same way as it used in your transport table. If you have `mx.myhost.com:587` then you need to use

```
mx.myhost.com:587 user:pass
```